# SSRS report on querystring param value

Tags: reporting-services

I have one report with a dropdown which contains all the countries and report can be viewed after selecting any countries from the dropdown as parameters. Till this it is fine but now I want to pass country name via the querystring and select the passed country on the dropdown and show the report. How to do this.

Trying to pass the parameter via url like :

```
http://[servername]/Reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?[folder]/[reportname]&rs:Command=Render&Country=India
```

Comment: The examples you found when you googled didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

Open report with parameter Country = India:

```
http://[servername]/Reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?[folder]/[reportname]&rs%3aCommand=Render&Country=India
```

Open same report as PDF:

```
http://[servername]/Reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?[folder]/[reportname]&rs%3aCommand=Render&Country=India&rs%3aFormat=PDF
```